# Where does gcloud install kubectl command?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using this command `gcloud components install kubectl` to install kubectl in my laptop (Mac).

But I have an existing `kubectl` which was installed by `brew`. How can I know the full path of `kubectl` installed by `gcloud`? I can change PATH env var to point to this path.

Comment: What about using `gcloud info` ?

Comment: Use the `where kubectl` command.

Comment: `where` command will show the one installed by `brew`. I am looking for where gcloud installed

Comment: Use `where -a kubectl` to see all locations. However, the first example shows where it is installed based on $PATH, which is the value you want.

Comment: `-a` is not available in Mac. I think it is linux option only

Comment: The OS is an important detail you left out. On macOS try the `which` or `whereis` command.

Comment: From `gcloud info | grep -i kubectl` you can get output of kubectl: [<version<], Kubectl on PATH:[<path>]]